# Android: Link to dropbox and Login to account programmatically

Tags: java, android, authentication, dropbox, account

I am able to follow [these instructions](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android) to set up dropbox for an android app. However, I want to able able to log in to the desired account programmatically. The instruction startlink like this to prompt for login.

> mAccountManager.startLink((Activity)MyActivity.this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);

How can I log in programmatically so that the user is not prompted?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:

```
        if(mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()){
            mAccount = mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount();
        }
        else{
            mAccountManager.startLink((Activity) MyActivity.this, prefs.getInt("REQUEST_LINK",0));
        }
```

The drop box api will store the account on the device, the user will have to log in the first time and then the above code will use getLinkedAccount() to automatically login to dropbox.